# Add Tooltip to node's icon

Tags: extjs4.2, ext.net

I have a tree of nodes and each node has its own icon.
what I want to do is to add a tooltip for each node's icon.
In fact, using qtip will add a tooltip to the whole node (node row) and it is not what i need.
So is it possible to do that in somehow?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement it in a similar way as it is done in [this example](http://examples.ext.net/#/Miscellaneous/ToolTips/GridPanel_Cell_Tooltip/).

Set a respective .Delegate for a ToolTip.

Define a custom attribute in a Node's CustomAttributes that contains a tooltip text for the icon and show that in a ToolTip's onShow.

Comment: Thanks Daniil for your reply